# Filter Search with Check box php

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i have issue about when i search data all checkbox will checked. i want is when i search data . Then data showed must be checked.

example i search the word "vin". only the word have vin must checked/true

**this is my html**

```
<input />
<table >
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="AvailableGroupLab availGrpLabs avalLabs">
    <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox'/></td>
        <td><span>wewe</span>

        </td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
        <td><span>Melvin</span>

        </td>
        <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
        <td><span>Marvin</span>

        </td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**this is my script**

```
function filter(element) {
    var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tr').hide();
    var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');

    var $valid = $trs.filter(function () {
        return regexp.test($(this).children(':nth-child(2)').text())
    }).show();
    $valid.find(':input:checkbox').attr("checked",true);

    $trs.not($valid).hide()
}

$('input:text').on('keyup change', function () {
    filter(this);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should clear other `input:checkbox` the checked attribute.

and when the `$(element).val()` is ""  should be return false or not ?

like this :

```
$trs.not($valid).hide().find(':input:checkbox').attr("checked",false);
```

Comment: @skip, it is a suggestion use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: but this answer is ryt :)

Comment: i have some issue i want is when the textbox is empty all the checkbox is checked or when i back it. this is a last question.

Comment: while the textbox empty ,regexp.test(value)  will return true,so all checkbox will checked.   @Satpal thanks

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you want... but you can try with `:contains`

```
function filter(element) {

var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tr').hide(),
    $value = $(element).val();
  var $searchedElement = $("span:contains(" + $value + ")");
  $searchedElement.parents('tr')
                  .find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true)
                  .end()
                  .show();
}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/N6SHq/)

Comment: Why its all checked? when i search?